# Сравнение дат

Tags: javascript, дата

Здравствуйте!

Нужно сравнить две даты формата d.m.Y H:i (пример: 25.05.2013 21:45).

Пробовал так:

```
 var sravn_one = new Date(date_one);
 var sravn_two = new Date(date_two);
 var sravn_one_time =
 sravn_one.getTime(); var
 sravn_two_time = sravn_two.getTime();
 if(sravn_one_time>sravn_two_time) alert("One");
```

Но этот способ не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данный вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// нужно привести дату к Y-M-D H:I:S
// или
function parseDate(date){
    return new Date(date.replace(/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/, '$3-$2-$1'));
}

if( parseDate('25.05.2013 21:45') > parseDate('25.05.2013 21:00') ){
    alert("One");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил данную проблему сам с помощью регулярки

```
"/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})/".
```